# How to view `lib*-doc`?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I'm going to write an interface for a shared library, but I'm having problem viewing the api/documentation on Linux.
I've installed `lib*-doc` in Linux (`libraw-doc` in Linux Mint). Is there a standard way of viewing this documentation (like `man` pages)?

Answer (score 0):

File list, libraw-doc http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/libraw-doc/filelist

They are mostly html pages, to be read in the default `Internet browser', like Firefox.

Comment: I agree that this is one way, but it requires finding the documentation for every package and opening it in the appropriate software. What I was wondering about is if there is a command line tool to automatically open the documentation?